# Difficulty returning values with recursive functions

Tags: python, recursion

So I'm writing a recursive function to determine an integer's membership in a list with binary search algorithm and I'm having trouble returning/printing a value once the function finishes its recursion. To be completely honest, I'm having difficulty wrapping my mind around recursion. Whenever I run the program it outputs half of an error message infinitely. My problem seems to be that if the item should fail the recursion test, it doesn't really know when to stop failing, it just keeps printing the failing condition/the error message that comes.

It's mandatory that the program prints out the condition once it finishes running, so that if I say is_member(list_of_numbers, 83) it will print "True" if it is in the list.

This is the code I have thus far after a few hours of work.

```
def is_member(set, number):
    if len(set) == 0:
        print(False)
    else:
        midpoint = len(set) // 2
        #print(midpoint)
        if set[midpoint] == number:
            print(True)
        else:
            if number < set[midpoint]:
                if is_member(set[:midpoint], number) == True:
                    print(True)
            elif number > set[midpoint]:
                if is_member(set[:midpoint+1:], number) == True:
                    print(True)
            else:
                print(False)


testlist = [0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42,]

is_member(testlist, 3)
is_member(testlist, 19)
```

Comment: You may be having difficulties returning values because at no point do you return anything from your function.

Comment: + when the length of set becomes 0, the `if` condition is run infinitely. Length of set if never < 0, so the print statement always executes.

Answer (score 0):

Your current recursive program does not run, because of the following condition -

```
if is_member(set[:midpoint+1:], number) == True:
```

Even when `midpoint` is `0` , this would call `is_member()` with the `set` slice as - `set[:1:]` - which would be the first element from `set` list. Hence, it this would keep on continuing. The condition should really be -

```
if is_member(set[midpoint+1:], number) == True:
```

So that you check the right side of `midpoint` .

Given that, to convert you program to return the result, you should return the result instead of `print` . Example -

```
def is_member(set, number):
    if len(set) == 0:
        return False
    midpoint = len(set) // 2
    if set[midpoint] == number:
        return True
    if number < set[midpoint]:
        return is_member(set[:midpoint], number)
    elif number > set[midpoint]:
        return is_member(set[midpoint+1:], number)
    return False
```

Demo -

```
>>> def is_member(set, number):
...     if len(set) == 0:
...         return False
...     midpoint = len(set) // 2
...     if set[midpoint] == number:
...         return True
...     if number < set[midpoint]:
...         return is_member(set[:midpoint], number)
...     elif number > set[midpoint]:
...         return is_member(set[midpoint+1:], number)
...     return False
...
>>> testlist = [0, 1, 2, 8, 13, 17, 19, 32, 42,]
>>>
>>> is_member(testlist, 3)
False
>>> is_member(testlist, 19)
True
>>> is_member(testlist, 100)
False
>>> is_member(testlist, 42)
True
```

Comment: Will returning the boolean values True and False print them outside of the shell? When this function is fully operational it has to print the values True and False and from what I've gathered "returning" only prints within the shell.

Comment: No it wouldn't, simply print the returned value as - `print(is_member(testlist, 42))` .